# In my C# code I get compiler error CS0029 when I try to define the return of my IEnumerable Task. How can I correct it?

Tags: c#, return, task, ienumerable

In my following C# code I get compiling error when defining the return of my IEnumerable Task (last line of my code)

Compiler Error Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply>'

How should I correct my code?

```
private async ValueTask PingMachine() 
{
  var timesToPing = 4;
  var counter = 1;

  while (counter <= timesToPing) {
  var reply = await Pinger(counter);
  counter++;
  }
}

private async Task<IEnumerable<PingReply>> Pinger(int counter)
{
  List<string> addresses = new List<string>();
  if (Check_IP_Correct(TagService.IP_PLC_List) == true) 
  addresses.Add(TagService.IP_PLC_List);

  var tasks = addresses.Select(async ip =>
  {
  var result = await new Ping().SendPingAsync(ip, 1000));
  TagService.log_PLC.AppendLine($" Pinged {ip} {counter} times time:{result.RoundtripTime} status: {result.Status.ToString()}");
  });
  return await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // This line  I am getting the compiler error
}
```

Comment: Your async lambda expression doesn't return anything, so the type of `tasks` is just `IEnumerable<Task>`. I suspect you just need `return result;` in the lambda expression...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your lambdas (`async ip => { ... }` ) don't return anything. Therefore, they are simply of type `Task`, not `Task<PingReply>` as you expect.

To fix, either add `return result;` to the lambda, or change `Pinger()` to return `Task`, since you don't use the result anyway.